# Convert unicode back to text - Wordpress JSON api

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, api, unicode

Working on a Wordpress feed on an external site and have encountered an issue with post titles that contain characters such as single quotes and dashes.

JSON output looks like this:

```
{"rendered":"Some title post text here &#8211; some text after dash"}

{"rendered":"&#8216;Title text in quotes &#8217;: More title text"}
```

What's the best way to convert these unicode characters back to text on the front end? At the moment it's displaying the unicode.

Thinking there must be a javascript solution. Ideally the solution would cover all bases.

Comment: Have you looked for a solution?

Comment: I have but part of the problem is knowing what to search for! I was thinking it must be a common problem but can't find much about it online.

Comment: This appears to be a useful resource? http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/188/encode-and-decode-html-entities-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with VUEjs you can use the v-html directive

Comment: You are an angel, you know that?!

Answer (score 1):

One *(sort of hacky)* way is to use the browser to unescape the string: you can insert the original string to an element (as HTML) and read back the text value.

With the help of jQuery:

```
var result = $("<div/>").html("&#8216;Title text in quotes &#8217;: Dash: &#8211; ").text();
```

The `result` then contains the unescaped plain text.

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ppbd58jk/

Answer (score 1):

They're actually HTML entities, you can add them to an HTML element and then read them again like so.

```js
function html_entity_decode(message) {
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.innerHTML = message;
  return element.innerHTML;
}
console.log(html_entity_decode("Some title post text here &#8211; some text after dash"));
console.log(html_entity_decode("&#8216;Title text in quotes &#8217;: More title text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an NPM package that performs this and it's well documented.
[html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text)

```
const { convert } = require('html-to-text');

const text = convert('<div>Nope Its not Ashton Kutcher. It is Kevin Malone. <p>Equally Smart and equally handsome</p></div>', {
    wordwrap: 130
});
console.log(text); 
// Results:
// Nope Its not Ashton Kutcher. It is Kevin Malone.

// Equally Smart and equally handsome
```

Assuming you're using a front end framework like React:

```
import { convert } from 'html-to-text';

export function App(props){

return (

  <div>
    <h1>{convert(props.wpData, {wordwrap: null})}</h1>
  </div>

    )}
```